# PHP : How to get all variable name in php post method

Tags: php

I would like to get and display all variable names which are posted by `method="post"` in a form. I am not aware of variables which passed from post method in HTML. Is there any method to list the all variables posted by post method ?.. Thanks in advance.

example:
http://www.dhamu.in/oncreate2.php?workload=10&request_type=project&name=web%20design&description=we%20have%20done%20it&budget=1&bidperiod=11&project_guidelines=checked&job_113=1&xxxx=10
Here i do no the variable name "xxxx"

Comment: The above is a GET, not a POST

Comment: `print_r(array_keys($_POST))` and for what you actually posted, which is a GET  `print_r(array_keys($_GET))`

Comment: If its for debugging purpose, I suggest you use either `var_dump($_POST)` or `phpinfo(INFO_VARIABLES)`

Answer (score 21):

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
  echo "{$key} = {$value}\r\n";
}
```

And BTW, those are `$_GET` variables (so adjust the above to use `foreach ($_GET as $key => $value){`.) You can also use `$_REQUEST` to cover both.

Comment: @Downvoter: What about this answer is wrong or inaccurate? Care to comment on what can be improved instead of just -1?

Comment: answer is correct but use this  >>>> echo "{$key} = {$value} <br/>"; >>> for new line

Comment: hardly worth a -1. Just a comment would have sufficed.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

`print_r(array_keys($_POST))`

... for just the keys.

Or:

`print_r($_POST)`

... for all the POST keys and values.

Answer (score 1):

To output all POST variables, try this:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Variables which are included within the URL are GET variables actually:

```
var_dump($_GET);
```